# SQL script stops executing and prints rest

Tags: sql, oracle, command-line

I have a SQL script that has a list of create commands. I run it in SQLPlus, using the Command Line. After each create command, there is a commit. Every time I run the script, it stops after the first commit, and prints the rest of the sql script with line numbers.

I have added the forward slash "/" to the end of the script but it does the same thing.

Could this have to do with the database's settings?

```
CREATE TABLE NAME_ACTIONFILE_STAGING_T
( 
RECORD_ID                   NUMBER(19),
JOB_ID                      NUMBER(19),
CRN_TIME                    TIMESTAMP,
FILE_NAME                    VARCHAR2(32),
ACTION_CODE                 VARCHAR2(32),
ACTION_NBR                VARCHAR2(32),
LINE_NBR                    NUMBER(3),
ACTION_FROM_SITE              VARCHAR2(32)
ACTION_TO_SITE                VARCHAR2(32)
PK_STRT_TIME            TIMESTAMP,
PK_END_TIME             TIMESTAMP,
DV_STRT_TIME          TIMESTAMP,
DV_END_TIME           TIMESTAMP,
ITEM_NAME                   VARCHAR2(12),
ACTION_QTY                    NUMBER(6),
VOLUME                       NUMBER(10),
RECNT                       NUMBER(5),

CONSTRAINT SF_STAG_PK PRIMARY KEY (RECORD_ID)
);
commit;
```

This is where the script quits and starts printing line numbers

```
CREATE OR REPLACE
SEQUENCE NAME_SF_STAG_SEQ
START WITH 1000
INCREMENT BY 1
CACHE 20;
commit;

end;
/
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: You have a dangling end; in there. Is there a begin somewhere ?

Comment: Oh dear. no... I just have some set statements and a comment. lol. Let me retry

Comment: Take that end out. And no need for commits

Comment: Commits aren't needed because DDL commit implicitly. The `/` you have now will just repeat the previous command (`commit` at the moment). You're missing some commas in the `create table` but they would error. You'd see odd things if you have `set sqlblankslines off` too. Maybe the problem is in part of the script you haven't shown?

Comment: This is why commas go on the left.